# How to use Twilio in my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twilio

I have followed a walk-through on how to set up Twilio in my web application, but I am getting an "Argument cannot be null" error.

Walk-through: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-sms-and-email-two-factor-authentication

Everything seems to be exactly as he put it, but I am getting an error. If anyone knows why I am getting this error or can spot a difference in my code that would be great.

My Code:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
   <add key="SMSAccountIdentification" value="My Identification" />
   <add key="SMSAccountPassword" value="My Password" />
   <add key="SMSAccountFrom" value="My Number" />
</appSettings>
```

.

```
public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var Twilio = new TwilioRestClient(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountIdentification"],
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountPassword"]);
        var result = Twilio.SendMessage(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountFrom"],
            message.Destination, message.Body
        );
        Trace.TraceInformation(result.Status);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I removed my identification, password, and number but they are correct from Twilio. I simply copied and pasted them.

Also, the rest from the walk-through is exactly the same.

The error occurs on the following line:

```
var result = Twilio.SendMessage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountFrom"],
            message.Destination, message.Body)
```

I have also confirmed that message is not null.

Comment: On what line does the null argument exception occur? Seems like IdentityMessage is the likely culprit here.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that.

Comment: It's on: var result = Twilio.SendMessage(System.Configuration.Configuration.Manager.AppSettings["SMSAccountFrom"], message.Destination, message.Body);

Comment: Without actually seeing more code, I would think that either message.Destination or message.Body is probably null or an empty string, I'd have to look at the API to see if either is allowed to be null. What do you see when inspecting the message object in debug mode?

Comment: Yeah, according to the API (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), Destination and Body would both be required - make sure those aren't null.

Comment: After inspecting message I found that it is not null. Both destination and body have values.

Comment: Have I entered the information correctly into the web.config file? I don't quite understand that area.

Comment: Web.config looks about right. You are running this on localhost?

Comment: Is there more code that you want to see? The methods behind weren't edited at all, but I can post those too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89338/discussion-between-tieson-t-and-jon).

Comment: The error says: Argument cannot be null. Parameter name: from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error arose because all data coming from my web.config was null. I discovered this by hard-coding values in and it worked. Upon further investigation I discovered that I was using the wrong Web.Config file. I should have been using the global one, but instead I was accidentally using the one in Views.

In short, I was getting null values because I was using the incorrect web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

From, destination, or body is null. The error is that an argument provided is null. You should check the values of what you are passing.

Comment: Thanks, it ended up being the values from the web.config file.